Integrating Microsoft Label Infrastructure for Printing QR Codes in C# and Creating Custom Label Templates
I'm working on a C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web project where I need to generate QR codes and print them using Microsoft Label Infrastructure. However, I'm facing some challenges in integrating the label infrastructure and creating custom label templates. Here's what I need help with:

Generating QR codes in C#: I have a C# codebase that generates QR codes and simply add to the PDF and Download it.
Printing QR codes using Microsoft Label Infrastructure: I need guidance on how to utilize Microsoft Label Infrastructure to print the generated QR codes. Specifically, I'm looking for methods or APIs in C# to interface with the label infrastructure for printing.
Setting the page according to printers: I need assistance in dynamically setting the page layout according to different printers. How can I achieve this programmatically in C#?
Integrating label numbers/schemes: I want to incorporate label numbers or schemes into the printing process, similar to Microsoft Office label templates. Are there any built-in features or libraries in C# that can help with this?
Selecting label type when printing: Users should be able to select the label type (e.g., OL875) when printing the QR codes. How can I implement this functionality in C#?
Creating custom label templates: Lastly, I need to create custom label templates for printing the QR codes. What approaches or tools can I use to design and implement custom label templates within my C# application?

Any insights, code examples, or recommended libraries/tools would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Reference Images:


